# How to make a policy for pivot table?

Tags: php, laravel

How to make a policy that checks if kid belongs to a user?

I have User and Kid model that have many to many relationship. If i just write

`return $user->id === $kid->user_id;` 
in my KidPolicy update method

and in my UpdateKidRequest extends FormRequest in authorize method

`return $this->user()->can('update', $this->route('kid'));`

in my postman update kid request it returns "This action is unauthorized.", because i do not have user_ id in my kid table instead it is in pivot table which also have kid_id. Can somebody help me how can I make policy to check if kid belongs to user so that user can update that kid table?

Comment: So do you want to add data of kids when adding user?
like : $u = User::create($userData); $u->kids($kidsData);

Comment: @Vishal Tarkar yes i will have users in my app that have kids and I want that my user can, create, update and delete everything about it's own kids but not the kids from other users.

Comment: Just added relationship in your user & kid model class.